# ionic run browser --livereload not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, windows-8.1, livereload

i was trying to use live  reload on my ionic 2 application. so i found this command

```
ionic run browser --live-reload
```

is not working as expected and while making code changes i am receiving console messages

```
[16:12:47]  build started ...
[16:12:47]  transpile update started ...
[16:12:47]  transpile update finished in 46 ms
[16:12:47]  deeplinks update started ...
[16:12:47]  deeplinks update finished in 248 ms
[16:12:47]  webpack update started ...
```

but the page isn't reloading

Comment: the syntaxis is `ionic run browser --livereload`.
If it doesnt work, check the workarounds at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/790

Comment: i tried `ionic run browser --livereload`   but the same behavior. **P.S. there isnt any workaround mentioned on that page**

Comment: **workaround**: after the change, wait until when the console shows the file changed and then rsync -rtv www/ platforms/browser/www or run another file watcher: fswatch -r www/ | xargs -I % rsync -rtv www/ platforms/browser/www

**workaround 2** ./node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build

Answer (score 25, accepted):

i found the solution on the github page

> include a script in the package.json file

```
"browser": "ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build"
```

and run

```
npm run browser
```

Comment: `ionic-app-scripts serve` is not the same as `ionic cordova run browser` as it does not support cordova plugins (while at least some of the plugins are supported for browser platform)

Comment: I'm sorry only now I get that this is a workaround to use the browser build and can confirm it works for me. I'd add to the answer explicit statement that this way we can have the cordova plugins and the browser platform working in a same way as for `cordova run browser`

Comment: Perfectly solved the issue mentionned in the question, thanks

Comment: @MathieuCastets `Ionic 2` is tagged in the question.

Comment: Works perfectly, and now I can use cordova-plugin-googlemaps (native map) on browser with live reload

Answer (score 13):

When you run the command `ionic cordova run browser --livereload` you will see something like this in CLI:

```
[19:39:00]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/ 

[INFO] Development server running
       Local: http://localhost:8100
       External: http://192.168.0.51:8100
```

Just open http://192.168.0.51:8100  or http://localhost:8100 and your live reload will work on that address. Your browser might have opened in http://localhost:8000 instead of 8100

Comment: Opening on 8000 is not the same as 8100 because, cordova is not running on 8100. The app on 8000 will have cordova in it.

Comment: indeed on 8100 the plugin proxies are not created

Comment: Worked for me anyway. sql plugin works on 8100 and not 8000

Comment: Ups! Yeah: 8100 is right, not 8100. :|
Many thanks, my Friend!

Answer (score 4):

First off, should anyone need this answer, the command has been renamed in the later version to

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

Second, The **--livereload** flag is not supported when you run this command. [this issue explains more](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2312)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

ionic cordova run browser --livereload  --consolelogs --serverlogs
```

Comment: For the benefit of others that find your answer, would you be able to explain why your solution works for this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
"serve": "npx ionic serve --cordova --platform browser"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this command browser will be reloaded automatically.

```
ionic serve
```

If you want to run application with different platform in browser you can use this command :

```
ionic serve -l
```

This both command will reload page automatically on code change

Comment: cordova is not loaded in ionic serve

Comment: browser is a platform `ionic serve` does not emulate/builds as browser platform