# Ionic 3 progressive web app. How to create normal app as progressive web app

Tags: ionic3

What is Progressive web app. If i want to create ionic 3 progressive web app what i need to add extra in my application. what are the resources. Like if app should run as PWA what are the things we need to add in the code. how can we make normal application into progressive web app.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195402/ionic-3-publish-app-as-pwa-progressive-web-app

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/

Comment: This is very clear: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

Answer (score 0):

Remove comment of this script from index.html file :

```
<!--script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
</script-->
```

and then run ionic run: build

PWA is totally depend on responsiveness of your website. And Ionic is the better way to develope responsive web app. We prefer ionic for PWA because we dont need to do extra as for building pwa.

But I said we prefer. We can build the PWA of any existing website or non-ionic websites. How ever this might some manual processes to do. For more refer to this article. [5minutesPWA](https://medium.com/@amitgandole)