# Deploying Ionic2 application

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I deploy my ionic 2 application on the production server, I am getting the errors below. But when I run the application on the localhost, it runs fine.

```
vendor.js:1349 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at main.js:1
```

Below is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <script data-ionic="inject">
    (function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.9.2';i.angular='5.0.3';i.staticDir='build/';})(window);
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <ion-app></ion-app>
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "WJC",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2", <=== latest
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am using some un-compatiable version types.

I copy the contents of my www folder into my Web application, then I make a war file and deploy on my server running tomcat.
Ionic build comes from

> ionic serve

Then for war file I do maven install.

This package.json seems to be working, this is from another app which I created few months ago. As you can see that here ionic version is a bit older than the latest one I'm using which is referenced in the app that's not working.

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.12.1", 
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase": "4.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.4.2", <=== Older
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^2.0.2",
    "noman.arain.plugin": "file:../noman.arain.plugin",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
    "ionic": "3.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "myAwesomeApp: An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "noman.arain.plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": {},
      "cordova-universal-links-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

My question has nothing to do with the `serviceWorker`.
I do not want to run these two commands:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic build browser --prod --release
```

ionic serve should suffice when I want to deploy my app.
Please remove this as the duplicate of the other.

Comment: how do you deploy your application & where? where is your build?

Comment: I updated my post to address your questions

Comment: I see I need to see the index.html of your build

Comment: I have posted my index.html

Comment: No the index.html of your build not src. I really can't help you like this. But you should know the error comes from the path of the vendor.js

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the index.html from the www folder.

Comment: Did your app run fine in server at the very first time?

Comment: Thank you Duannx. No, I think once I updated, the apps did not work at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 3 publish app as PWA (Progressive Web App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195402/ionic-3-publish-app-as-pwa-progressive-web-app)